# What is equivalent to `redis - zADD` in aerospike using php

Tags: php, aerospike

I am new to aerospike and I have few questions, some things that I could not understand from the documentation.

I tried to do something simlar on aerospike (please see the example below) but I am not sure if it is the right way:

Redis client:

```
$cache_key = "some.cache_key.1111";
$multi->zAdd($cache_key,534,"39e9a447af489f97d5047ba5aa304ec7");
```

Redis command:

```
ZRANGE some.cache_key.1111 0 -1 withscores
133683) "39e9a447af489f97d5047ba5aa304ec7"
133684) "534"
and so on..
```

1. how make aerospike database contain similar structure like redis `$cache_key = "some.cache_key.1111";` the number `1111` can change from time to time but with different data (key/value)?
2. How I can loop through all the key/value in bins ?

```

```
$key = $db->initKey('test','votes','pk');
$bins = [ 'my_bin'=> ['6d69f5c66fb77c561059600f24664669' => 2222 ]];
$status = $db->put($key, $bins);
if ($status !== Aerospike::OK) {
    var_dump($status, $db->error());
}

$key = $db->initKey('test','votes','pk');
$bins = [ 'another_bin'=> ['6d69f5c66fb77c561059600f2466466a' => 333 ]];
$status = $db->put($key, $bins);
if ($status !== Aerospike::OK) {
    var_dump($status, $db->error());
    exit(1);
}
$status = $db->get($key, $record);
var_dump($record);
```

```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  'key' =>
  array(4) {
    'ns' =>
    string(4) "test"
    'set' =>
    string(15) "votes"
    'key' =>
    NULL
    'digest' =>
    string(20) "����4�)q\�\000 ꤑ>��"
  }
  'metadata' =>
  array(2) {
    'ttl' =>
    int(2592000)
    'generation' =>
    int(28)
  }
  'bins' =>
  array(2) {
    'my_bin' =>
    array(1) {
      '6d69f5c66fb77c561059600f24664669' =>
      int(2222)
    }
    'another_bin' =>
    array(1) {
      '6d69f5c66fb77c561059600f2466466a' =>
      int(333)
    }
  }
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Aerospike has support for ZLIST type operations through the [SortedMap](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-map.html) datatype. However, the PHP client does not yet implement the map or list API fully.

Look at the Python client's implementation of [map functions](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.map_set_policy).

Comment: By the way, this is in progress.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a estimated time?

Comment: I don't, since I'm not writing it myself, but it is under development.